# Is it Possible to create or make Tree Structure view in android in the same way that Tree Overview in the Android SDK?

Tags: java, android

I want to achieve tree structure view in my app and it should scroll in both horizontally and vertically at the same time, exactly same as the Tree Overview(which is used to find Layout structure) in the Android SDK. Please please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean TreeMap?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html

I'm sorry, the part where you ask for Tree in Android, for Tree in Android, in the subject is a little confusing. I hope this helps?

Comment: Check out the below link

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=tree+overview+android&es_sm=125&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ViBgVfztB46fuQSXy4PACw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1093&bih=525&dpr=1.25#imgrc=2FVNhJIlpmSgkM%253A%3Bmt-w0uEMfw21DM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.techotopia.com%252Fimages%252F6%252F65%252FAndroid_studio_tree_overview.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.techotopia.com%252Findex.php%252FDesigning_a_User_Interface_using_the_Android_Studio_Designer_Tool%3B349%3B298

Comment: I wanted to display the tree structure visually to the user, like I mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

For treeView here is an library
https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView
I hope this will help you

Comment: Please add some info here too. Don't just provide links.

Comment: Not file tree @payal tuteja, here is the image link it'd would help you understand the context of my question.

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MVCe2onfMTo/T1zanSW-thI/AAAAAAAAAqw/iuK_kFlAjm4/s640/Tree%2Bview%2Busing%2BXML%2Bdata%2Bfrom%2BJava%2BServlet%2Band%2BMySQL.gif

Comment: Any luck with finding the tree view ?